# How to run RMI in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, rmi

We can run RMI in netbeans by following steps.

Right click build.xml -> Run target -> Other targets -> startRMI

But what i need is to start RMI registry through Java code. Is it possible? Help me.

Comment: http://forums.netbeans.org/post-8076.html&highlight=
http://blogs.sun.com/branajam/entry/rmi_and_netbeans

Comment: there is a tutorial for running a hello world rmi sample using netbeans here:
http://javaconsultanat.wordpress.com/2012/08/15/hello-world-rmi-using-netbeans/

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation Class:

```
YourClass extends UnicastRemoteObject implements YourService {
  ...

  System.setSecurityManager(new java.rmi.RMISecurityManager());
  registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry( 1099 );
  Naming.rebind("rmiName", this);
}
```

Comment: This code is working after starting the RMI registry (manually) only. Otherwise it shows the below error 

java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.1.35; nested exception is: 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Answer (score 1):

You should at first start the 'rmi server' and then the client. For this take a look at [this tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html) section 'Implement the server'.

BTW: I would recommend to use [hessian library](http://hessian.caucho.com/) which works over http!! so your admins do not need to explicitely open some ports for your app!